# MS Access - protecting backend file

Tags: ms-access

I'm creating a split database in Access which has the backend on a drive accessible to all employees in the company at the moment. This isn't such a big deal at the moment because I'm still developing it and have a backup of the file.

The main reason I did this was because the protected drive I intended to use didn't allow read/write access and stopped my VBA code from executing.

As the database goes live it will be important that no one can move or delete my backend file, but I'm unsure how to approach this issue. Is there anything I can do to protect/hide this file to stop anything happening to it?

(Backing up will be done regularly regardless)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about setting special permissions to the folder containing the backend file. [This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419) has a table that might help.